# Is there a way to map a PHP error constant to its name (or a human readable one)?

Tags: php, error-handling

There are various [PHP error constants](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) describing various errors and warnings.

While I can manually map these error constants to their corresponding values, is there a better way to have these mapped to the name of the constant, or even better, their human-readable name (E_NOTICE --> "PHP Notice")?

Comment: To what purpose? *How* do you plan on using this?

Comment: I'm trying to do something that most MVC frameworks do... set a custom handler to show custom errors, instead of the default PHP ones that print errors out in the middle of content.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood well what you want.
I hope to be your help.

```
function ErrorType($type) 
    { 
        switch($type) 
        { 
            case E_ERROR: // 1 // 
                return 'ERROR'; 
            case E_WARNING: // 2 // 
                return 'WARNING'; 
            case E_PARSE: // 4 // 
                return 'PARSE'; 
            case E_NOTICE: // 8 // 
                return 'NOTICE'; 
            case E_CORE_ERROR: // 16 // 
                return 'CORE_ERROR'; 
            case E_CORE_WARNING: // 32 // 
                return 'CORE_WARNING'; 
            case E_COMPILE_ERROR: // 64 // 
                return 'COMPILE_ERROR'; 
            case E_COMPILE_WARNING: // 128 // 
                return 'COMPILE_WARNING'; 
            case E_USER_ERROR: // 256 // 
                return 'USER_ERROR'; 
            case E_USER_WARNING: // 512 // 
                return 'USER_WARNING'; 
            case E_USER_NOTICE: // 1024 // 
                return 'USER_NOTICE'; 
            case E_STRICT: // 2048 // 
                return 'STRICT'; 
            case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR: // 4096 // 
                return 'RECOVERABLE_ERROR'; 
            case E_DEPRECATED: // 8192 // 
                return 'DEPRECATED'; 
            case E_USER_DEPRECATED: // 16384 // 
                return 'USER_DEPRECATED'; 
        } 
        return ""; 
    }
    function xhandler($errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline,$context)
    {
        $errno = ErrorType($errno);
        error_log("PHP ".$errno.":  ".$errstr." in ".$errfile." on line ".$errline);
    }
    set_error_handler('xhandler',E_ALL);
```

Comment: Is it always guaranteed that the error constant wont be a bitmask combining many of them? The error constant page mentions that it is a bitmask (but doesn't explain any further as to if its ever used that way). (This is actually also the exact reason why I was looking for a PHP builtin or some such...)